# Close Button for Twitter Bootstrap3 Tabs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I try to follow from this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MBehtemam/UMFH5/) to adding close button to Twitter Bootstrap Tabs but i can't create a close button correctly.this is my [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ruvet/1/edit?html,output) codes. how can i make a close. i try to create with `a` tag but tabs make my link block level when i have 2 link in one li.

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Tab 1 <button><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></a>     </li>
    <li><a href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tab 3</a></li>
  </ul>
```

**Solution**

I forget to insert `class="close"` for button so the correct is :

```
<button class="close"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
```

Comment: Where is your Javascript code?

Comment: I'm only need style and correct position for button .

Comment: I find it , i forget to insert `class="close"` for button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add class `close` to the button.